# Cleanup Berkeley DB log files

Tags: berkeley-db

I'm running a nightly script that executes `db_hotbackup` on multiple Berkeley environments but in addition to that I need to be able to cleanup the log files in the source dir. I am aware of `db_archive` but that seems to only work if the Berkeley environment is closed (or doesn't exist ).

So I'm thinking about changing my script to do the following:

```
`db_hotbackup -cv -h $1 -b $backup_dir`
`db_recover -h $1`
`db_archive -h $1`
```

Is this the best solution?

Comment: db_archive works with open environments...

Answer (score 1):

Running "db_archive -d" will eliminate database log files.
You can also set DB_LOG_AUTO_REMOVE to automate what "db_archive -d" does.

Running "db_recover" without -e will eliminate __db* dbenv
files (but may require an idle database).